# Mouseover instead of click

Tags: 6, blocks

Has anyone gotten the Quicktabs module to work on mouseover/hover instead of click?
There was a [patch for version 6.x-2](http://drupal.org/node/288902#comment-1152480) that does not work with the current version.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up making a couple of edits to quicktabs.js. At its most basic, in line 24 I changed 'click' to 'mouseenter' and changed the name of the `quicktabsClick()` function to `quicktabsHover()`.

When the user clicked the link in the tab, though, the page refreshed; I added the following at line 25 (below the new call to quicktabsHover):

```
$(this).unbind('click').bind('click', quicktabsClick);
```

I also added a new function:

```
var quicktabsClick = function() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You are not making changes to the modules JS files are you?

Comment: I did, yes. And I'm making sure not to update.

Comment: @jay-ess Make a patch and submit to Drupal.org

Comment: @Nikhil - This really needs to be something that is configurable, which I did not do and is out of my league. I believe there has been some talk about making it so, but I have not revisited.